# version control with minimum hassle

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, bazaar

I'm looking for a program, that is capable to monitor file deletions/creation/renames and issues appropriate version control commands automatically. Using bazaar and subversion. Is there any?

Comment: What would be these "*appropriate* version control commands" for example? Add, commit, delete?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to automate this. You should be committing changes manually when you intend them to be made.

Comment: hugh, what are appropriate commands for deletion or rename? ;) no commits, of course. That would be stupid.

Answer (score 1):

For Subversion, TortoiseSVN allows you to [fix renames](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/351) and it also allows to add and commit unversioned items with a single click. These options are manual but I believe the functionality is good enough: you don't want to automate such stuff because computers are not very smart and they definitively cannot read your mind ;-)

Comment: no I do want ;) and not single click, actually. And what about deletions?

Comment: Deletions are handled as well. And I presume most GUI tools do so. I guess you don't actually use VC software for the purpose we all think :)

Comment: really? What tsvn do, when u deleted file not with tsvn?

Comment: The file appears in the list of modified stuff with a "missing" label.

Answer (score -2):

This looks very dangerous.  Suppose you have 2 related files that you both want to change.  You can delay the save in your IDE until you have made all the changes, but the IDE will be unable to save them at the exact same moment (it will be very close but there can be some milliseconds in between).  As soon as the first file is changed the automated procedure will perform the commit, causing an inconsistency in your application.

What you probably want is a system that allows you to go back to your own changes in case you screwed up your own local code.  SCITOOLS had a tool called TRACKBACK which exactly did this.  Unfortunately they don't sell this anymore.

Comment: hey, where ur found the word "commit" in my question?

Comment: In subversion terminology, a commit is a set of inserts/updates/deletes towards the version management system.  Therefore.

Comment: thanks, C.O.
I ask, why you write about commits. I didn't ask for this.

Comment: Because the concept of committing is integral to the concept of version control.  Its like ask why someone mentions bread when you asked about how to make a sandwich.

Comment: I didn't ask for any auto-commits. Period.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a sandwich and when we give you one, you simply say you're not hungry.  Strange.

Comment: I'm looking for a steak and you are trying to give me burger. Saying, that fastfood is bad for health ;)